# Cant read images (multiple uploads) php

Tags: javascript, php, html, file

I am having an issue reading the images form my controller.php file once the data is submitted.

On the UI side images are working fine, they are visible on upload but as mentioned, once I pass I tried to read the values they arent found.

I am trying to read the files by name img_name by it cant seem to find it. Can anyone spot why that is?

Thank you all in advance.

Here is my code.

```
<script>
    console.clear();
('use strict');


(function () {

  'use strict';
  
  // Four objects of interest: drop zones, input elements, gallery elements, and the files.
  // dataRefs = {files: [image files], input: element ref, gallery: element ref}

  const preventDefaults = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  };

  const highlight = event =>
    event.target.classList.add('highlight');
  
  const unhighlight = event =>
    event.target.classList.remove('highlight');

  const getInputAndGalleryRefs = element => {
    const zone = element.closest('.upload_dropZone') || false;
    const gallery = zone.querySelector('.upload_gallery') || false;
    const input = zone.querySelector('input[type="file"]') || false;
    return {input: input, gallery: gallery};
  }

  const handleDrop = event => {
    const dataRefs = getInputAndGalleryRefs(event.target);
    dataRefs.files = event.dataTransfer.files;
    handleFiles(dataRefs);
  }


  const eventHandlers = zone => {

    const dataRefs = getInputAndGalleryRefs(zone);
    if (!dataRefs.input) return;

    // Prevent default drag behaviors
    ;['dragenter', 'dragover', 'dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(event => {
      zone.addEventListener(event, preventDefaults, false);
      document.body.addEventListener(event, preventDefaults, false);
    });

    // Highlighting drop area when item is dragged over it
    ;['dragenter', 'dragover'].forEach(event => {
      zone.addEventListener(event, highlight, false);
    });
    ;['dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(event => {
      zone.addEventListener(event, unhighlight, false);
    });

    // Handle dropped files
    zone.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);

    // Handle browse selected files
    dataRefs.input.addEventListener('change', event => {
      dataRefs.files = event.target.files;
      handleFiles(dataRefs);
    }, false);

  }


  // Initialise ALL dropzones
  const dropZones = document.querySelectorAll('.upload_dropZone');
  for (const zone of dropZones) {
    eventHandlers(zone);
  }


  // No 'image/gif' or PDF or webp allowed here, but it's up to your use case.
  // Double checks the input "accept" attribute
  const isImageFile = file => 
    ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/svg+xml'].includes(file.type);


  function previewFiles(dataRefs) {
    if (!dataRefs.gallery) return;
    for (const file of dataRefs.files) {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        img.className = 'upload_img mt-2';
        img.setAttribute('alt', file.name);
        img.src = reader.result;
        dataRefs.gallery.appendChild(img);
      }
    }
  }

  
  const imageUpload = dataRefs => {

    // Multiple source routes, so double check validity
    if (!dataRefs.files || !dataRefs.input) return;

    const url = dataRefs.input.getAttribute('data-post-url');
    if (!url) return;

    const name = dataRefs.input.getAttribute('data-post-name');
    if (!name) return;

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(name, dataRefs.files);

    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log('posted: ', data);
      if (data.success === true) {
        previewFiles(dataRefs);
      } else {
        console.log('URL: ', url, '  name: ', name)
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('errored: ', error);
    });
  }


  // Handle both selected and dropped files
  const handleFiles = dataRefs => {

    let files = [...dataRefs.files];

    // Remove unaccepted file types
    files = files.filter(item => {
      if (!isImageFile(item)) {
        console.log('Not an image, ', item.type);
      }
      return isImageFile(item) ? item : null;
    });

    if (!files.length) return;
    dataRefs.files = files;

    previewFiles(dataRefs);
    imageUpload(dataRefs);
  }

})();
</script>

        <h1 class="h4 text-center mb-3">Drag &amp; drop file upload example</h1>
    
<form action="Controller/createadcontroller.php" method="post">
    
      <fieldset class="upload_dropZone text-center mb-3 p-4">
    
        <legend class="visually-hidden">Image uploader</legend>
    
        <svg class="upload_svg" width="60" height="60" aria-hidden="true">
          <use href="#icon-imageUpload"></use>
        </svg>
    
        <p class="small my-2">Drag &amp; Drop background image(s) inside dashed region<br><i>or</i></p>
    
        <input id="upload_image_background" data-post-name="image_background" name="img_name" class="position-absolute invisible" type="file" multiple accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/svg+xml" />
    
        <label class="btn btn-upload mb-3" for="upload_image_background">Choose file(s)</label>
    
        <div class="upload_gallery d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center gap-3 mb-0"></div>
    
      </fieldset>
    
    
    
      <fieldset class="upload_dropZone text-center mb-3 p-4">
    
        <legend class="visually-hidden">Image uploader</legend>
    
        <svg class="upload_svg" width="60" height="60" aria-hidden="true">
          <use href="#icon-imageUpload"></use>
        </svg>
    
        <p class="small my-2">Drag &amp; Drop logo image(s) inside dashed region<br><i>or</i></p>
    
        <input id="upload_image_logo" data-post-name="image_logo" class="position-absolute invisible" type="file" multiple accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/svg+xml" />
    
        <label class="btn btn-upload mb-3" for="upload_image_logo">Choose file(s)</label>
    
        <div class="upload_gallery d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center gap-3 mb-0"></div>
    
      </fieldset>
    
    </form>
    
    
    <svg style="display:none">
      <defs>
        <symbol id="icon-imageUpload" clip-rule="evenodd" viewBox="0 0 96 96">
          <path d="M47 6a21 21 0 0 0-12.3 3.8c-2.7 2.1-4.4 5-4.7 7.1-5.8 1.2-10.3 5.6-10.3 10.6 0 6 5.8 11 13 11h12.6V22.7l-7.1 6.8c-.4.3-.9.5-1.4.5-1 0-2-.8-2-1.7 0-.4.3-.9.6-1.2l10.3-8.8c.3-.4.8-.6 1.3-.6.6 0 1 .2 1.4.6l10.2 8.8c.4.3.6.8.6 1.2 0 1-.9 1.7-2 1.7-.5 0-1-.2-1.3-.5l-7.2-6.8v15.6h14.4c6.1 0 11.2-4.1 11.2-9.4 0-5-4-8.8-9.5-9.4C63.8 11.8 56 5.8 47 6Zm-1.7 42.7V38.4h3.4v10.3c0 .8-.7 1.5-1.7 1.5s-1.7-.7-1.7-1.5Z M27 49c-4 0-7 2-7 6v29c0 3 3 6 6 6h42c3 0 6-3 6-6V55c0-4-3-6-7-6H28Zm41 3c1 0 3 1 3 3v19l-13-6a2 2 0 0 0-2 0L44 79l-10-5a2 2 0 0 0-2 0l-9 7V55c0-2 2-3 4-3h41Z M40 62c0 2-2 4-5 4s-5-2-5-4 2-4 5-4 5 2 5 4Z"/>
        </symbol>
      </defs>
    </svg>
```

Reading the files uploaded

```
echo $_FILES['img_name']['name'];
```

It is printing blank.

Comment: If you want to upload multiple files under the same name, you need to use `[]` in the field name, and the $_FILES structure PHP provides will also be different than for a single file upload, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php Also, use `var_dump` for debug outputs rather than echo. Look at the full thing, that will provide the most insight: `var_dump($_FILES);`

Comment: Thank you for the help, I changed name to img_name[] and added var_dump to login any issues, it show NULL, still does seem to be working. I am working if 'name' needs to be place somwhere else in the HTML.